# Does bundling CSS files break CSS Intellisense in Razor views?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Does including a set of bundled CSS files in a layout view, a la `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` stop css class intellisense in slave View files?

I ask because in one of my views, `View.vbhtml`, I typed:

`<div class="` and there was no Intellisense recommending any of the css classes established in the bundled css files.

I haven't tried without bundling - I assume bundling is causing it, as VS 2012 must have css class intellisense, no?

Answer (score 0):

No, intellisense isn't going to work for bundled files.

Styles in `.css` files aren't going to ".Render" until runtime.

Lastly, I've tested this over and over again, I can't even get intellisense if I use:

```
...
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #myElement{color:red}
        .myStyle{color:red}
    </style>
</head>
...
```

in the _Layout.cshtml itself.

CALL TO THE WILD: if I'm incorrect in this, I challenge you to provide Definitive proof AND an example we can replicate, otherwise we have to conclude that no there isn't intellisense in MVC Views

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I was noticed the intellisense works fine when I was editing a nopCommerce template. CSS intellisense worked fine there in sub pages also.

Answer (score 0):

I observed a similar issue with VS2012 and ASP.NET MVC Razor views. While researching the suggestions/answers and comments in related to this topic I was unable to apply any that worked successfully in my VS2012 ASP.NET MVC Razor projects. However,  I did uncovered details from Microsoft Connect acknowledging this as a yet to be implemented feature as well as a solution that did work in my VS2012 where all other suggestions have not worked in my VS2012 environment

You can see these details here: [CSS Intellisense not working for MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987476/css-intellisense-not-working-for-mvc-4-project-in-visual-studio-2012-ultimate/17481806#17481806)