# CSS Intellisense not working for MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Have created a brand new Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate SP2 MVC4 project but unable to get CSS class selector intellisense to work?

When I type `<p class="m"` .... I should get the class "myClass" appearing in intellisense dropdown but nothing happens.

The file I have listed below is: `\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`

Any Ideas ?

**Edit:**  Have re-installed VS2012 on brand new windows 7 system (running on Mac OSX parallels 8) and still acting in the same way. Also seems the same for MVC 3 projects.

[image]

Extensions installed:
[image]

Comment: Did you get this working by any chance? I have just encountered the same problem while trying to use bootstrap in MVC.

Comment: I have the same issue... Any resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Web Essentials 2012 extension for Visual Studio 2012: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6?SRC=VSIDE

And/Or

Try adding Microsoft Web Developer Tools extension.

I have both of these and using your same example the intellisense works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't work. I have Web Developer Tools extension installed already and have just installed the Web Essentials 2012 but that doesn't have made any difference. Have added screenshot of what I have installed in the original question.

Comment: If you move the CSS to a dedicated .css file does the intellisense work?

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above mentioned remedies and suggestions. None of these worked in my environment.  According to Microsoft (Under Microsoft connect's bug id 781048), they have not implemented CSS class intellisense for MVC/Razor files but are working on including this in a future release.

I have a 10 minute webcast example of extending VS2012 intellisense that adds one solution that will add intellisense to your VS2012 environment: [a Visual Studio Intellisense Extension](http://1drv.ms/1iQhoTW)

The webcast uses MEF to extend Visual Studio to add an intellisense completion source that scans the currently loaded project for CSS class names to add as an intellisense completion set. Here is the css completion source class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Operations;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities;
using EnvDTE;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace CssClassIntellisense
{
   internal class cssClassList
   {
      public string cssFileName { get; set; } //Intellisense Statement Completion Tab Name

      public HashSet<string> cssClasses { get; set; }
   }

   internal class CssClassCompletionSource : ICompletionSource
   {
    private CssClassCompletionSourceProvider m_sourceProvider;
    private ITextBuffer m_textBuffer;
    private List<Completion> m_compList;
    private Project m_proj;
    private string m_pattern = @"(?<=\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+(?=\ {|{|,|\ )";
    private bool m_isDisposed;

    //constructor
    public CssClassCompletionSource(CssClassCompletionSourceProvider sourceProvider, ITextBuffer textBuffer, Project proj)
    {
        m_sourceProvider = sourceProvider;
        m_textBuffer = textBuffer;
        m_proj = proj;
    }

    public void AugmentCompletionSession(ICompletionSession session, IList<CompletionSet> completionSets)
    {

        ITextSnapshot snapshot = session.TextView.TextSnapshot;
        SnapshotPoint currentPoint = (SnapshotPoint)session.GetTriggerPoint(snapshot);

        if (TargetAttribute.Inside(currentPoint))
        {
            var hash = new List<cssClassList>();
            //read any .css project file to get a distinct list of class names
            if (m_proj != null)
                foreach (ProjectItem _item in m_proj.ProjectItems)
                {
                    getCssFiles(_item, hash);
                }

            //Scan Current Editor's text buffer for any inline css class names 
            cssClassList cssclasslist = ScanTextForCssClassName(
                    "Inline", snapshot.GetText());

            //If file had any css class names add to hash of files with css class names
            if (cssclasslist != null)
                hash.Add(cssclasslist);

            var _tokenSpanAtPosition = FindTokenSpanAtPosition(session.GetTriggerPoint(m_textBuffer), session);

            foreach (cssClassList _cssClassList in hash)
            {
                m_compList = new List<Completion>();
                foreach (string str in _cssClassList.cssClasses.OrderBy(x => x))  //alphabetic sort
                    m_compList.Add(new Completion(str, str, str, null, null));

                completionSets.Add(new CompletionSet(
                    _cssClassList.cssFileName,    //the non-localized title of the tab 
                    _cssClassList.cssFileName,    //the display title of the tab
                    _tokenSpanAtPosition,
                    m_compList,
                    null));

            }
        }
    }

    private ITrackingSpan FindTokenSpanAtPosition(ITrackingPoint point, ICompletionSession session)
    {
        SnapshotPoint currentPoint = (session.TextView.Caret.Position.BufferPosition) - 1;
        ITextStructureNavigator navigator = m_sourceProvider.NavigatorService.GetTextStructureNavigator(m_textBuffer);
        TextExtent extent = navigator.GetExtentOfWord(currentPoint);
        return currentPoint.Snapshot.CreateTrackingSpan(extent.Span, SpanTrackingMode.EdgeInclusive);
    }


    private void getCssFiles(ProjectItem proj, List<cssClassList> hash)
    {
        foreach (ProjectItem _item in proj.ProjectItems)
        {
            if (_item.Name.EndsWith(".css") &&
                !_item.Name.EndsWith(".min.css"))
            {
                //Scan File's text contents for css class names
                cssClassList cssclasslist = ScanTextForCssClassName(
                    _item.Name.Substring(0, _item.Name.IndexOf(".")),
                    System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_item.get_FileNames(0))
                    );

                //If file had any css class names add to hash of files with css class names
                if (cssclasslist != null)
                    hash.Add(cssclasslist);
            }
            //recursively scan any subdirectory project files
            if (_item.ProjectItems.Count > 0)
                getCssFiles(_item, hash);
        }
    }

    private cssClassList ScanTextForCssClassName(string FileName, string TextToScan)
    {

        Regex rEx = new Regex(m_pattern);
        MatchCollection matches = rEx.Matches(TextToScan);
        cssClassList cssclasslist = null;

        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            //create css class file object to hold the list css class name that exists in this file
            cssclasslist = new cssClassList();
            cssclasslist.cssFileName = FileName;
            cssclasslist.cssClasses = new HashSet<string>();

        }

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            //creat a unique list of css class names
            if (!cssclasslist.cssClasses.Contains(match.Value))
                cssclasslist.cssClasses.Add(match.Value);
        }

        return cssclasslist;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!m_isDisposed)
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            m_isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

As an FYI, you can also address this issue using Resharper. But that is a 3rd party product that needs to be purchased for Visual Studio

Comment: ReSharper is very expensive - I use it myself but suggesting a tool that costs hundreds of dollars isn't really an answer to OP's question is it? Especially since it's possible to get this sort of result _without_ ReSharper in this case.

Comment: Understood about the cost. However since none of the previously answers provides a solution that works to provide CSS class intellisense with VS2012 MVC razor views. I believe it is helpful to know up front that MS has not implemented this feature yet to avoid thinking this is a VS2012 issue. And my mention of ReSharper is the option that Did work for albeit at cost.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just CSS intellisense that's failed or has it completely stopped throughout Visual Studio?

I had a similar issue that effected the whole of my Visual Studio 2012. It was a while back but I remember deleting a folder from my appdata. Take a look at this link, hopefully it will help:
http://www.haneycodes.net/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-not-working-solved/

Comment: It's just CSS intellisense for MVC projects. Web Forms projects seem to work ok. Have tried deleting the folders you suggest but no joy. Have also uninstalled VS2012 several times and re-installed but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to get intellisense for CSS in VS2012 for Razor views. There is a workaround to use intellisense. Just create one test view(.aspx) using ASPX view engine and include your css file there. Now intellisense will work in new aspx view. All you have to do is copy paste the css class from aspx to Razor view(.cshtml or .vbhtml). I hope this helps.