# Why am I not getting .css intellisense

Tags: asp.net, intellisense, single-page-application, durandal, hottowel

**Question:** Why am I not getting `.css` intellisense while coding the HTML in Durandal `~/App/Views/###.html` pages.

**Steps to Recreate:**
In Visual Studio Professional 2012 I've began an "empty" ASP.NET Web Application and added [*Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.0.0*](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.0.0) [Nuget](http://nuget.org/) Package to my solution. I've also included [*Durandal 1.2.0*](http://nuget.org/packages/Durandal/) and [*Bootstrap 2.3.1*](http://nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap/).

After adding the above mentioned references to my application I've added a `shell.html` page to the `~/App/` folder that was generated when [Nuget](http://nuget.org/) installed the [*Durandal*](http://nuget.org/packages/Durandal/) package.

As a sidenote, the `.css` files are working fine once I debug the application. I have multiple `.css` files including the `Bootstrap.css` file (installed with [*Bootstrap 2.3.1*](http://nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap/) (mentioned above)) in my `~/Content/` folder and the `~/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` which are referencing and using the `.css` files as they should during runtime.

Lastly, when I go through the [*PluralSight*](http://pluralsight.com/training/) [*Single Page Apps JumpStart*](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=single-page-apps-jumpstart&highlight=john-papa_spajs-m1-spa%2a1,0#spajs-m1-spa) tutorial and get to the [*Coding the Shell with Durandal.js*](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=single-page-apps-jumpstart&highlight=john-papa_spajs-m1-spa%2a1,0#spajs-m1-spa) section we see clearly that I'm/we're supposed to get intellisense, but I do not.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I was just made aware  "*[the issue has been routed to the Visual Studio Product Team for triage and resolution.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/790808/no-intellisense-in-html-editor-to-show-the-classes-in-my-css-file)*"

Comment: Did you solve this problem as I've still not found a solution? I'm the person who you reference above in your "P.S" sentence.

Comment: This still is not resolved. However I'll reiterate that your question is similar however I'm going to remove that "P.S. This [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987476/css-intellisense-not-working-for-mvc-4-project-in-visual-studio-2012-ultimate/16489840#16489840) is similar to mine however it's unanswered." remark from my initial post as the question is too dis-similar. Your question is about CSS in MVC whereas my question is specific to CSS intellisense not showing in Durandal `~/App/Views/###.html pages, as it does in the Pluralsight.com video I reference in my OP.

Comment: I am having the same issue while working on the SPA JumpStart course you mentioned. I asked the author (@John_Papa) why that may be the case and he responded with "ReSharper". http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ So that tool may be needed to get the VS intellisense that we desire with this kind of project structure.

Comment: Placing `bootstrap.css` in a folder named "Content" solved this for me.

Comment: I'm in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate now so I'm unable to test. Thanks for your reply @Ian Chu Te, maybe it will help someone using 2012, or in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS should work in VS 2012. I always install Web Essentials too, as it helps tremendously (its like an incubator for VS features between releases)

For the JavaScript intellisense ... when using require.js it is harder to get that. THe best way I found is to use Resharper's plugin for VS. It gives me intellisense on JavaScript, even when using require.js.

Comment: FWIW, I have VS 2012.3 and I was not getting intellisense for the bootstrap CSS names when creating a div either. I installed Web Essentials for 2012 (http://vswebessentials.com/download) just now and it still doesn't work after restart. Looks like I will go with ReSharper if I can't live without intellisense for js/css.  Awesome course though, thanks John!

Comment: I too am appreciative for and always install and enjoy the benefits of the Web Essentials download however it doesn't resolve the above mentioned issue. Resharper is as well a great tool but this issue is focused on CSS intellisense in .cshtml files. I'm thinking (based on the fact that you have CSS intellisense in .cshtml) that this issue may be patched for you by a different package?

Comment: SIDENOTE: My Web Essentials install is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding an explicit bootstrap.css reference in the Site.Master (I am using master pages in my app)

```html
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
```