# Visual Studio intellisense for css files

Tags: css, visual-studio, intellisense

In my MVC projects I get `IntelliSense` for all `js` files referenced in `_references.js` which is all great and good.

Is there a similar way to reference `css` files to be picked up by the Visual Studio `IntelliSense` feature?

Comment: possbile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987476/css-intellisense-not-working-for-mvc-4-project-in-visual-studio-2012-ultimate